# How to get a variable value from a test method with TestNG Listeners

Tags: java, testng, testng-dataprovider

I'm using TestNG to run automation tests. I also implemented TestNG Listener to save the test results in a certain format.

For some specific scenario I need to do the following:
When a test runs, a value is assigned to a variable (local method variable).
I need to pass the value of the variable to the TestNG Listener class I implemented. There are various methods (ontestStart, onTestFinish, onTestSuccess/Failure/Skipped), but I cannot figure out how to get the variable at run time.
And I didn't find it in TestNG documentation.

Can anyone please help? Or share his/her experience with a similar issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try by [listening to the method invocations](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#invokedmethodlistener) and set values into the [`ITestResult`](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/IAttributes.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)).
Then you'll find the values from `ITestResult` into [your custom reporter](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging-reporters).

Comment: Thanks! Finally solved it today. Basically the test method should accept the argument of type ITestContext. In the body of the test I set the attribute to it, and in the listener (onTestFinish), I get the attribute from the ITestResult result.getContext.getAttribute("myAttribute").

Comment: thanks. BTW, do you know how to debug in this situation? I'd lik to put the breakpoint in the Listener and stop for example at the onTestFailure (which is implemented in the Listener). But when I run the test from IDE, it won't stop at the Listener.

Comment: When you say IDE, I suppose you mean Eclipse because I haven't the problem with IntelliJ. You should ask your question on the testng mailing list.